# Is there a way to extract text if charcter length is given using twitter-text?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am using [twitter-text](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text) to get the length of the tweet. As like how twitter highlights if the character count is more than 140 chars, I need to implement the same functionality.

I just need to get x chars from the given text using twitter-text length algorithm.

Something like this method

```
twitter.txt.getTweetTextForGivenLength(text, charLength)
```

Comment: `substr`, `substring`?

Comment: @Tushar No, See `getTweetLength` method in [twitter-text](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/js/twitter-text.js).

Using this algorithm I need to extract text for given length